# JavaFx - Shapes disappear when rotating axe is big

Tags: java, animation, javafx, rotation

I am trying to rotate a sphere around another sphere in javafx. Somehow, when I change my camera translate to new Translate(0, 0, -100), the shape disappears when it reaches the far end of the screen and can't figure out how to solve. Here's my code so far:

```
Sphere earth = new Sphere(2);
    earth.setTranslateZ(7);
    earth.setTranslateX(28);
    RotateTransition rt4 = new RotateTransition();
    rt4.setNode(earth);
    rt4.setDuration(Duration.millis(3000));
    rt4.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    rt4.setByAngle(360);
    rt4.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    rt4.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rt4.play();

PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    camera.getTransforms().addAll (
            pivot,
            yRotate,
            new Rotate(-22, Rotate.X_AXIS),
            new Translate(0, 0, -100)
    );
```

I marked in this picture the position where the shape earth disappears [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOR05.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like the value of [`farClip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Camera.html#farClipProperty) is too small.

Comment: setFarClip() did indeed do the trick. Thank you :)